# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.(not show view)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to display my information in a view, but when I try to test I get the following error!

I do not know how to fix it!

I am using a tuple that contains a list and an int.

The problem seems to be from here!

If anyone has a solution, thank you for telling me!

Thanks in advance to those who help me!

Error text:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 
'System.Tuple`2[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.DTOs_viewmodels_.Course.ShowCourseListItemViewModel],System.Int32]',
 but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Core.DTOs_viewmodels_.Course.ShowCourseListItemViewModel]'.
```

Comment: Can you show place where `GetCourse` is called and how `Tuple` is passed into view?

Comment: In the controller and action related to View and in the Return View section. I added in the code! @demo

Comment: I can see only one issue here - `Index` action detects some other View then what you expect. Please double check what View name is used for `Index` action